# Concat several JS modules using GCC with transpiling from ES2015 and injecting variables annotated with @define

Tags: javascript, java, gcc

I'm trying to create a Java web-service which serves JavaScript files with some information injected in these files depending on request. Here's an example of what I have in my `javascript` dir:

**main.js:**

```
import {log} from "./lib";

/** @define {string} */
const SCRIPT_ID = "SCRIPT_ID"
let foo = "bar";
log(foo);

// Rest of code
```

**lib.js**

```
export function log(str) {
    console.log(">>>", str);
};
```

I'd like these scripts to

1. be concatenated in one file;
2. wrapped in `(function() { /* concatenated scripts */ })();` to prevent pollution of global namespace;
3. be modified to replace some pieces of code with some variables from Java (like `SCRIPT_ID` in `main.js`).

I'm using Google Closure Compiler for this with following Java code:

```
CompilerOptions options = new CompilerOptions();
options.setLanguageIn(CompilerOptions.LanguageMode.ECMASCRIPT6);
options.setLanguageOut(CompilerOptions.LanguageMode.ECMASCRIPT5);
options.setInlineVariables(CompilerOptions.Reach.ALL);
options.setDefineToStringLiteral("SCRIPT_ID", "12345");
```

Well, it doesn't work. The `SCRIPT_ID` is not injected (because I compile two files at once), and I can't wrap the combined result in self-invoking function, because I can't find a way of doing it when using GCC from Java. If you're using GCC command line tool you can supply `--output_wrapper` option for that, but it seems to work only for cli tool.

Does anybody know how to work this around?
Maybe there's a better JavaScript compiler? GCC seems to be really good at optimizing JavaScript, but it doesn't suit my case.

**UPDATE**

Regarding `@define` statements I could work around it placing all variables to be annotated with `@define` in a separate file which *doesn't use ES6 modules keywords, i. e. `import`, `export`*:

**globals.js**

```
/** @define {string} */
let SCRIPT_ID = "";

/** @define {boolean} */
let DEBUG = true;
```

If you send this file to the compiler along with other files then things work as expected, annotated variables replaced with corresponding values from Java code.

Answer (score 0):

As workaound you could read the JS files into memory, concat and wrap them, and then use `JSSourceFile.fromCode` to build a single source file and feed this into the compiler.

Comment: Nice idea, but what about @define annotations?

Comment: @coquin this should work as intended. (It should also work if you compile more input files at the same time)